# Embed private AGOL webmap with automatic authentication

Tags: arcgis-online, authentication

We're a subcontractor on a larger project that involves generating client-specific reports. Clients must log in to see these reports (HTML pages), and we'd like to embed a private ArcGIS Online (AGOL) map within these pages.

Is it possible to set permissions such that by virtue of being on the report page, they are allowed to see the private map? Is there any way for this page to pass credentials automatically, so that the client will never see them?

This is an example of a private AGOL map (you should be greeted by a username/password screen): http://stone-env.maps.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=6b13e08c1cab4b399c7a79b61cb654ba

We'd like this to be embedded in a page, and have it visible automatically to the client when they're on this page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your best option here is going to be a self-hosted proxy service. Normally this is used for access to AGOL Premium services, but it should also be able to solve your problem.
https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/working-with-proxies/

As far as I can tell, the ArcGIS Online hosted proxy workflow is only for premium services embedded in applications and would not work with just secured web maps, though Esri tech support might know better on that one.

Comment: Got it. Looking at the [premium services example](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/10/07/public-access-to-arcgis-online-premium-services/), it seems like I'd still run into the issue of actually viewing a private webmap. 

The user would be able to see secured services within the webmap, but wouldn't be able to access the webmap without a username/password. Is that your sense too?

Comment: Yes, that patterns only works for the services inside an otherwise public web map. You definitely do not want to go that right because it basically makes your secured services public! I have used the self-hosted proxy before successfully (but the pattern for it depends on specifics to your web server deployment that you probably do not want to get into here). The nice thing about the self-hosted proxy is that you can also white list the domains that can access it (basically limiting access so that it only comes from inside your client reports).

Comment: Ah, thanks for your patience. Took me a little while, but I totally get it. Using the self-hosted proxy we restrict access to the data (in an otherwise-public webmap) to only traffic from our client reports. Perfect! Thank you so much!